# DIS 2012 sponsorship proposal

Tags: discussion, speakers-bureau

The [2012 International Workshop on Deep Inelastic Scattering and Related Subjects](http://www.dis2012.uni-bonn.de) in Bonn (Germany) is coming up at the end of next month. I'm scheduled to give a talk there, but my adviser has asked me to look for external sources of funding to cover the trip. So naturally I thought of Stack Exchange and its [speakers' bureau program](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/).

**Why is this of interest to the community?**

DIS 2012 will be attended by a lot of accomplished high-energy physicists. In particular, representatives of the major experiments at CERN and elsewhere will be presenting their latest results, so anyone who follows the latest trends in high-energy physics will be interested to know what is presented at the conference. I can write up daily updates and post them on my personal blog, and I can also make an effort to ask relevant questions on the site.

**What is the benefit to Stack Exchange?**

Many of the physicists there also have teaching duties, and there will also be graduate students and postdocs giving presentations (at least, I assume I won't be the only one there who's not a professor). Even if these people may not be the type to ask questions on this site, they *are* in a great position to recommend us to their students or members of the public. So this is an opportunity to get more people aware of this site. I can also mention other related SE sites which may be of more interest to the conference attendees - I'm specifically thinking of [Theoretical Physics](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com) and [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com).

**What do I need?**

As I mentioned at the top, I'm looking for any funding sources that can replace some of the grant money that (I assume) I can get through my university. Since the potential benefit to SE is not as great as if I were going to a conference *specifically* to promote this site, I wouldn't presume to ask for a full sponsorship of the trip, but even, say, a contribution toward the cost of the hotel would be helpful. I already plan to acknowledge selected Stack Exchange sites in my presentation, but I think the acknowledgement might carry more weight if I could say "*sponsored* by Stack Exchange, Inc." People's ears tend to perk up when they hear that money might be available somewhere ;-)

Physicists don't go to conferences expecting to collect T-shirts, but if I had some small things to hand out like business cards, pens or pencils, or maybe even stickers, I could probably send a few people home with reminders of our network.

So what does the community think about this? Is it worthwhile? If not (or even if it is), I think we should keep in mind the possibility of sending someone as a representative of PSE to a more high-impact conference like next year's APS general meetings.

---

Updates:

- Success! Stack Exchange will be partially sponsoring my trip to Bonn and I will do my best to involve the Physics.SE community, perhaps including posting updates on this meta question. More details will be coming.
- Swag has arrived :-) I have some stickers, pens, and markers to hand out at the conference.
- I'll be mainly posting updates on [my blog](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/tagged/DIS%202012.html) and on [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/ellipsix), but I'll also add summaries to an answer to this meta question.

Comment: *"Physicists don't go to conferences expecting to collect T-shirts"* Well, the big conferences usually have *some* swag--a bag with a pen, a notepad and the schedule in it at least--and it's been down a bit recently. So maybe a freebie wouldn't hurt.

Comment: How do we get SEs attention on this? Do we need more people from the community to support it? AFAICT nobody visits the meta :(

Comment: More support is always better, but this should be good enough for now. I'll have to send them an email about it.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Any progress?

Comment: Nope, no response from SE.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Sorry about that! I'll check on the progress of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Deep Inelastic Scattering is, but physics.SE could *definitely* do with some promotion (I dunno about the other sites, but a little promotion never hurt anyone). Compared to the other SEs, we have much less activity. And we need more specialists, as is evident from [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Here's an idea I just came up with. In honor of the conference, I'll be putting bounties on between zero and two more DIS-related questions this week to increase their visibility and/or reward those who post good answers (with a preference toward new or low-rep users). So if you have a question on any topic related to the conference, this is the time to ask it!

---

At Shog9's request, I'll be posting some updates here as I put things up on my blog.

1. [What is Deep Inelastic Scattering?](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2012/03/what-is-deep-inelastic-scattering.html)
   I'm starting with a post that explains in basic terms what deep inelastic scattering is, as well as why it's important enough to have a conference named after it even if much of the subject matter of that conference is not directly related.
2. [Summary of plenary sessions](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2012/03/day-1-plenary-sessions.html)
   I've posted an overview of some of the plenary session talks, including recent results.
3. [Midweek report: Parallel Sessions](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2012/03/midweek-report-parallel-sessions.html)
   Here I just pointed to some potentially interesting presentations, but I'll have to come back and do analysis later.
4. [Day 5: plenary sessions (again!)](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2012/03/day-5-plenary-sessions-again.html)
   There is a *lot* to summarize from this conference, but for now I've posted a quick overview of some of the relatively general-interest points brought up at the concluding summary talks.

I did manage to get the word out about Stack Exchange to a few people at the conference! I gave out a few pens and markers (the stickers were less appreciated, though).